# Network debugging: Sudden rise in packet loss and latency

Tags: networking, debugging

My laptop sees a sudden rise in packet loss and latency (from 0.0%, 1ms to 70%, 2000ms).

It remains even after resuming from suspend-to-ram.

It remains after:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
sudo modprobe -r ath9k ath9k_common mac80211 ath9k_hw ath cfg80211 ath3k
sleep 1
parallel -j1 sudo modprobe ::: ath9k ath9k_common mac80211 ath9k_hw ath cfg80211 ath3k
```

It disappears after rebooting.

Syslog:

```
Sep 14 21:58:00 aspire NetworkManager[1610]: message repeated 13 times: [ <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted]
Sep 14 21:59:06 aspire NetworkManager[1610]: <info> sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Sep 14 21:59:06 aspire NetworkManager[1610]: <info> sleeping or disabling...
Sep 14 21:59:06 aspire NetworkManager[1610]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [100 10 37]
Sep 14 21:59:06 aspire NetworkManager[1610]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'sleeping') [37]
Sep 14 21:59:06 aspire NetworkManager[1610]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 10603
Sep 14 21:59:06 aspire kernel: [20833.291120] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:1b:fc:10:41:94 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Sep 14 21:57:50 aspire wpa_supplicant[1661]: message repeated 52 times: [ wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
Sep 14 21:59:06 aspire wpa_supplicant[1661]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:1b:fc:10:41:94 reason=3 locally_generated=1
```

uname -a

```
Linux aspire 3.16.0-31-lowlatency #43~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 10 20:41:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```